# PHP - Need to get the same thing using 3 very different id's from API

Tags: php, api

I need to be able to be able to get the same data from my database using 1 of 3 different ID's.
In this instance I am fetching shopping cart data using either a session_id (for guest users), account_id (for logged in users) or just by the cart's primary auto-incrementing key.

At the moment I have three GET API routes set up but I want to know if there's a more efficient way of accomplishing this

```
$router->get('carts/{id:i}', ['Controller\\CartController', 'getCartById']);
$router->get('carts/session-id/{sessionId:s}', ['Controller\\CartController', 'getCartBySessionId']);
$router->get('carts/account-id/{accountId:i}', ['Controller\\CartController', 'getCartByAccountId']);
```

A session_id is stored in a browser cookie with a TTL. A shopping cart will always have at least a session_id in the database but not always an account_id (signifying a guest user).

In this instance you are either logged in or a guest.

If the Cookie storing the session_id associated with a cart expires and you're **not** logged in we can assume that the cart has expired. If that guest user wants to add something to their cart again we will generate them a new one with a new session_id.
I think this chart explains things pretty well
[image: decision flow chart]

Comment: Can't you just always fetch by cartId?  Logged in or not, each cart will have an id, right?

Comment: You can store session-id for all types of users and get cart by session-id.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes but that ID will not always be accessible on the front end since the account ID is stored on login and the session ID is stored in a Cookie. We would generally only use that endpoint if we already had the cart from a previous call.

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh yes we store the session_id in a cookie but that cookie can expire. So in the event that there is no cookie and the user is logged in we would need to get the cart (if there is one) by using their account_id

Comment: @J_C  I don't understand how you would ever have a cart without an id.  A cart only exists if it has been created.  If it has been created, then it has an id.  Also, in response to "but that cookie can expire", you can always set the expiry to be _very_ far in the future.

Comment: @J_C  And how are you persisting a logged-in session if the cookies have expired?

Comment: You can put your session_id(cart_id) in the local storage and after the finalizing cart, you can remove that.

Comment: @PatrickQ the cart_id is always in the database but on the front end we are not storing the cart_id anywhere, just the session_id and account_id if they are logged in. 

I think I may have answered my own question though. The reason it has a TTL on the session_id is for garbage collection so if a guests session_id is not present we'll just make them a new cart. We will only get a cart one of those two ways as either of them must be present at all times to get a pre-existing cart